# Changes to Visual Studio Solution Configuration not reflecting on build machine

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I've set up "Team Foundation Build" (I think that's the correct name).  I have a build controller (build machine) that has been building our solution correctly.  When building on the build machine, I'm using a separate solution configuration.
We added a new project to the solution.  I've opened the configuration manager and checked the box for "Build" next to that new project while the configuration used on the build machine is selected.  This change to the solution is checked in.  But the build machine won't build that project.
If I make changes to solution configurations and examine the .sln file, I see those changes reflected so I know that information is stored there.  However, when I open the .sln file in Visual Studio on the build machine (after it's written there during a failed build), I see that the check box "Build" next to our new project is unchecked (thus explaining why it's not being built).  If I copy the .sln file from the build machine to my machine and compare it with the .sln on my machine (where the box is checked), they match!
I'm baffled...

Comment: Sometime mychanges to sln files arent there and then I always make a point to right click the teamproject node if only one project and then checkin all the changes. Then solution is updated on the server.

Comment: Are there any answers to this question or any workaround from @dude ?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the new project is in a folder in source control that is not specified in the TFS Build's definition's list of workspaces.
Edit the TFS Build definition and verify the list of working folders.
The solution file may contain this project reference but unless it is included in the working folders it will not be available to the build server.